# This Array is undefined but why?

Tags: arrays, angular, undefined

I want to check an Array until it's filled and show up a loading dialog but it always tells me

> this.events[0] is undefined

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.initMethod();
  if(this.events[0].start == this.books[0].date_from_og) {
    this.dialog.closeAll();
  } 
}
```

But events cant be undefined because it contains event of a calendar which get displayed.

```
  initMethod() {
    this.service
     .getEmployees()
     .subscribe(
     (listBooks) => {
       this.books = listBooks;
       this.events = this.books.map((book) => {
         return {
           start: new Date(book.date_from_og),
           end: new Date(book.date_to_og),
           type: ""+book.type,
           title: "" + book.device + "",
           color: colors.blue,
           actions: this.actions,
           resizable: {
             beforeStart: false,
             afterEnd: false
           },
           draggable: false
         }
       });
     },
     (err) => console.log(err)
   );
  }
}
```

And Constructor:

```
constructor(private modal: NgbModal, private service: BookingService, private dialog: MatDialog) {
   this.initMethod();

   this.dialog.open(DialogLaedt, {
      width: '650px'
   });
```

Comment: Show us the code of your `initMethod()` (if `this.events` is set from there)

Comment: Done @Nanotage.

Comment: Because your call to the service is asynchronous

Comment: @penleychan and that means? (Sorry but I'm new in Angular)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you `initMethod()` retrieves the result asynchronously.

So when you reach the line with `if(this.events[0].start == ...` there is no guarantee that the event data has been retrieved from the service yet.

The fix is to move your check inside the subscribe part of your init method (which executes as soon as the observable emits it's value), or let the init method return an observable that you can subscribe to, and perform your check inside that subscription.

#### Solution 1 - Moving your check inside subscription

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.initMethod();
}

initMethod() {
  this.service
   .getEmployees()
   .subscribe(
   (listBooks) => {
     this.books = listBooks;
     this.events = this.books.map((book) => {
       return {
         start: new Date(book.date_from_og),
         end: new Date(book.date_to_og),
         type: ""+book.type,
         title: "" + book.device + "",
         color: colors.blue,
         actions: this.actions,
         resizable: {
           beforeStart: false,
           afterEnd: false
         },
         draggable: false
       }

       if(this.events[0].start == this.books[0].date_from_og) {
         this.dialog.closeAll();
       } 
     });
   },
   (err) => console.log(err)
 );
}
```

#### Solution 2 - Letting your initMethod return an Observable

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.initMethod().subscribe(() => {
      if(this.events[0].start == this.books[0].date_from_og) {
          this.dialog.closeAll();
      } 
  });
}


initMethod() {
    return this.service
    .getEmployees()
    .pipe(tap(
    (listBooks) => {
        this.books = listBooks;
        this.events = this.books.map((book) => {
        return {
            start: new Date(book.date_from_og),
            end: new Date(book.date_to_og),
            type: ""+book.type,
            title: "" + book.device + "",
            color: colors.blue,
            actions: this.actions,
            resizable: {
            beforeStart: false,
            afterEnd: false
            },
            draggable: false
        }
        });
    }))
}
```

Comment: I have added an example for both scenarios

Comment: Thanks for ur answers but on the 2st Solution I still get the Error und on the 1st it says 'Unreachable code detected'

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that you are calling the *initMethod()* twice. Once in the *constructor*, and once in the *ngOninit* method.